# Split array rows with spaces in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

How I can get this

```
array = ["apple", "orange kiwi", "lemon"];
```

to this

```
array["apple", "orange", "kiwi", "lemon"];
```

split array row in multiple keys if there is space in it.

tnx

Comment: Careful with the vocabulary used here. The _keys_ in an array are the numbers used to access _values_. It would probably be best to speak of splitting entries or rows with spaces in them, but not keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join and split?

```
array = ["apple", "orange kiwi", "lemon"];

array = array.join(" ").split(" ");
```